# Executing External Code(with domain) within Externally Executing Code

Tags: c#

im using this code:

```
public class Launcher : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public static void Start(byte[] Exe, string Checksum)
    {
        string[] args = { IP, id, Checksum };
        Console.WriteLine("::Invokeing with: " + IP + ", " + id + ", " + Checksum);
        var ps = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
        var setup = new AppDomainSetup();
        setup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var ev = new Evidence();
        var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Sandbox",
            ev,
            setup,
            ps);
        var program = (Launcher)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            typeof(Launcher).Assembly.FullName,
            typeof(Launcher).FullName);
        program.Execute(Exe, args);
        AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
    }

    public void Execute(byte[] bytes, object[] args)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
        var main = assembly.EntryPoint;
        main.Invoke(null, new object[] { args });
    }
}
```

the thing is, the code which im executing with this, is also using this code however im getting this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Kan transparentproxy niet converteren
>   naar type Launcher.    bij Embassy.Program.Launcher.Start(Byte[] Exe,
>   String Checksum)

can anybody help me,
P.S. no unnessesary downvotes if you don't know the awnser.

> first excecuting works, second fails

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if you rewrite the function and put in an external dll like this:

```
public class Launcher : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Start(byte[] Exe, string[] args)
    {
        PermissionSet ps = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
        AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
        setup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        Evidence ev = new Evidence();
        AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Sandbox",
            ev,
            setup,
            ps);
        Launcher program = (Launcher)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            typeof(Launcher).Assembly.FullName,
            typeof(Launcher).FullName);
        program.Execute(Exe, new object[] { args });
        AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
    }
    public void Execute(byte[] bytes, object[] args)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
        MethodInfo main = assembly.EntryPoint;
        main.Invoke(null, args);
    }
}
```

and invoke it with new Launcher().Start('Source', new [] { "args"}); you'll get the desired result.